# Blender Text Not Rendering Over Background Colors

Tags: rendering, text-object, 2d

I am hoping someone can help with me this. I have text objects in my blender file which are positioned in front of other grease pencil objects (along the y axis). When I try to render the animation, the text does not show up. I noticed it is being blocked by the colors I have filled in the grease pencil objects. It's a 2D animation.

Not sure if I have some incorrect settings on the text objects.

I have uploaded my blender file here if anyone can help:

https://www.mediafire.com/file/d8n0nrmj7d8b7wg/Scene+1+-+Text+Issue.blend/file

I have also pasted a screenshot of what it should like and a screenshot of what actually shows up after rendering.

[image: What it should look like]

[image: What shows up after rendering]

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just downloaded your blend file, rendered and got:

[image]

so either you changed something in between or a miracle happened or is it not ok?

Comment: That's strange, what you have is what it should look like, but I just tried rendering it again and mine still doesn't show the text. I even downloaded the file I uploaded just to make sure. Since it works for you I wonder if there is some overall setting that I have that is off.

Comment: I couldn't figure it out from my laptop, but I tried rendering it on another computer and it worked fine, without changing any settings. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are welcome